# Determining if a coordinate is on a line

Tags: java, geometry, awt, line, coordinates

I´m coding a little app that allows the user to draw multiple shapes and then remove or resize them. It´s working perfectly on rectangles and ovals, but I´m having issues with lines.

Here´s a method that I wrote to find if the clicked spot on the screen is part of a specific line:

```
    public boolean containsLocation(int x, int y) {
    int m = (getY2() - getY()) / (getX2() - getX());
    int b = getY() - (m * getX());
    if (y == (m * x) +  b) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

I´m using the famous *y = mx + b* formula and replacing *y* and *x*, wich are the coordinates on the spot clicked, to find if the clicked spot is part of the line.

The original coordinates are determined using the getters getX(), getY() and getX2(), getY2()

The problem is when I click on the screen to remove the line, it only works if I click on the very fist coordinate (x,y) where the line starts.

Nothing happens when I click anywhere else along the line.

Since math is not a strongest suit, can anyone shed a light on what I´m doing wrong?

Here´s my Line full class:

```
    public class Line extends Shape{

private int x2, y2; 

public Line (int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color lineColor) {
    super(x, y, lineColor);
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getLineColor());
    g.drawLine(getX(), getY(), getX2(), getY2());

}

@Override
public boolean containsLocation(int x, int y) {
    int m = (getY2() - getY()) / (getX2() - getX());
    int b = getY() - (m * getX());
    if (y == (m * x) +  b) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public int getX2() {
    return x2;
}

public void setX2(int x2) {
    this.x2 = x2;
}

public int getY2() {
    return y2;
}

public void setY2(int y2) {
    this.y2 = y2;
}
```

}

Here´s the Shape class that is being extended by Line:

```
    public abstract class Shape {
    private int x, y;
    private Color lineColor;

     public Shape(int x, int y, Color lineColor) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.lineColor = lineColor;
    }

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
    public abstract boolean containsLocation(int x, int y);

    public int getX() {
    return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
    return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
    }

    public Color getLineColor() {
    return lineColor;
    }

    public void setLineColor(Color lineColor) {
    this.lineColor = lineColor;
    }

    }
```

Here´s the method that calls containsLocation:

```
    public Shape shapeFinder(int x, int y){
    for (int i = shapes.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
        if (shapes.get(i).containsLocation(x, y)){
            return shapes.get(i);
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

And here´s the method that should remove the line (it´s working for Ovals and Rectangles):

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (model.getAction() == Model.REMOVE) {
            startX = e.getX();
            startY = e.getY();
            shape = model.shapeFinder(startX, startY);
            if (shape != null) {
                model.getShape().remove(model.shapeFinder(startX, startY));
            }
```

Comment: `getX()` and `getY()` return `int`s?

Comment: It also falls over with division by zero on vertical lines, as ```getX2() - getX()``` is ```0```.

Comment: You need to provide more details. I'm guessing it's the exactitude that's biting you, but we need to see what getX() etc return. But just a thought... if the line runs from (100,100) to (120,153) it would be impossible to click on that line as there are no points on that line (save the endpoints) where both X and Y are integers.

Comment: I´ve tried with doubles and them casting them back to ints later, but it didnt work. I will paste my line class.

Comment: Put in some print line statements so you can see what all there variable values are.  That may help you narrow down which statement is causing the issue.

Comment: Rotation etc is overkill. I think your idea is ok except for vertical or near vertical lines. The biggest problem is that you're using integer division to calculate m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to compute the direction of the line (its angle in radians) using something like Math.atan2. Then, you can apply an inverse rotation to one of the points of the line, considering the other point as the center, and also to the mouse coordinate. Your line is now a horizontal one, so checking if the mouse is over it is straight-forward.

See rotation matrices.

```
public class LineDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(containsLocation(50, 75, 50, 50, 50, 100));
    }

    public static boolean containsLocation(int x, int y, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        double dy = y2 - y1;
        double dx = x2 - x1;
        double dist = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        double cos = Math.cos(-angle);
        double sin = Math.sin(-angle);

        double xRot = (x - x1) * cos - (y - y1) * sin;
        double yRot = (x - x1) * sin + (y - y1) * cos;

        // Actually, I only rotated the mouse point, since
        // I can use the first point of the line and its
        // euclidian distance to know where the rotated
        // second point would end.

        if (0 <= xRot && xRot <= dist) {
            double tolerance = 3; // distance tolerance in pixels

            if (Math.abs(yRot) <= tolerance) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use doubles. You can't do `float dist = Math.sqrt(...)` - that's an error since `sqrt()` returns a `double`.

Comment: True, a cast is needed. I often use floats instead of doubles to accomodate for the lack of FPU units on some Android devices. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Also, this just plain doesn't work. :) I tested with my example line of (100, 100) to (120, 153) and asked if (120, 153) was on that line and your code said no.

Comment: I'm sure there is a sign issue somewhere, sorry about that, I quickly wrote that without testing it. I shouldn't have :p I'll fix the error and will let you know.

Comment: At the point where you say `if (getX() < xRot && xRot < getX() + dist)` my xRot is equal to 56.648 when I start with (100, 100) to (120, 153) and test for (120, 153). You should be testing for xRot between 0 and dist. Also you need to test for equality, so: `if (0 <= xRot && xRot <= dist)`

Comment: Yeah, here´s not working either. But I appreciate the effort! Thanks a lot, Aurélien.

Comment: Hey, nice one! Indeed, I rotated the point with getX/Y as the center, so it should be relative to 0 now, and not getX/Y!

Comment: Actually, I wrote a lot of such code while making this kind of tools (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KASY91EiTXQ), but that was months ago so it's hard to get it right on the first try without testing :p

Comment: I edited my earlier comment but maybe you missed it... if you don't test for `xRot = 0` or `xRot = dist` then the endpoints aren't included. A minor detail but could be important...

Comment: I changed '<' to '<=', thanks. It usually doesn't matter much with doubles, but since we are converting ints to doubles, it may be critical.

Comment: Yeah, he's clicking on the screen so the numbers coming in are indeed ints. All I know is that without the equality test, inputting an endpoint (integer values) fails...

Comment: Line are still not moving or being removed. Pesky lines...I will provide more details.

Comment: I'm debugging, I'll find the problem, we're not far :)

Comment: FOUND IT! Actually, x must be between 0 and dist and not between x1 and x1+dist, and the same applies to y! I'll update the answer.

Comment: I changed my previous code to the one I used in my text editor to find the error. x1/y1 are the old getX/Y and x2/y2 are getX2/Y2. I hope you will be fine with it :)

Comment: Always a pleasure; I don't like being very close to the solution but not finding it. Plus it's cool to write code on a simple text editor and compile it with command line, that's a good training :)

Answer (score 2):

You're using integer division to calculate your slope. I used my example of (100,100) to (120, 153) and it gave me a slope of 2. It should be a slope of 2.65.

But regardless, you'll never find any integer points in the middle of my line - there are no points along my line where both x and y are integers. If you calculate the slope correctly you'll be able to get the endpoints recognized but you need to find a different way of calculating points in the middle. Maybe introduce some sort of epsilon to your method?

Comment: As an additional point I'd also warn that a line is infinitely thin so some range to it should probably be considered